# How to use an iOS device as an iBeacon in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ibeacon

I am new to beacon integration. using code to get the UUID of the iPhone beacon(transmitter).
initially, I wrote below code to get UUID of iPhone to act as a beacon

```
let uuidString = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString  
print("UUID == \(uuidString)")
```

UUID: F2830580-4E97-4098-B01A-99D49BB69EF1

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
var myBeaconRegion: CLBeaconRegion?
var peripheral: CBPeripheral?
var manager: CBCentralManager?
var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager?

override func viewDidLoad(){

    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.delegate = self
    locationManager?.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self as 
    CBPeripheralManagerDelegate, queue: nil, options: nil)

    let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "F2830580-4E97-4098-B01A-99D49BB69EF1")

    myBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid!,identifier: "iBeacon")

    myBeaconRegion?.notifyOnEntry = true
    myBeaconRegion?.notifyOnExit = true
    myBeaconRegion?.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true
    manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self as? CBCentralManagerDelegate, queue: nil)
    locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: myBeaconRegion!)
    locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(in: myBeaconRegion!)
    locationManager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Using delegate method to get the detected beacon

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion)
{

  //  let value = region.major  as? NSNumber
   beaconLabel.text = "Beacon not found!"
    let foundBeacon = beacons.first as? CLBeacon
    print("foundBeacon == \(foundBeacon)")
 guard let  discoveredBeacon = beacons.first?.proximity else {
 print("beacon not found")
 return
 }


    let proxyValue = foundBeacon?.accuracy
    beaconDistanceLabel.text = String(describing: proxyValue!)
 let background:UIColor = {

 switch discoveredBeacon {
 case .immediate:
    beaconLabel.text = "Immediate!"
    return  UIColor.green
 case .near:
    beaconLabel.text = "Near!"
    return  UIColor.orange
 case .far:
    beaconLabel.text = "Far!"
    return  UIColor.red
 case .unknown:
    beaconLabel.text = "Unknown!"
    return  UIColor.magenta
 }
 }()
 view.backgroundColor = background

}
```

delegate methods are calling but `CLBeacon` not detecting iPhone device.

Even i tried with
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/turning_an_ios_device_into_an_ibeacon but no results.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Finally i got solution how to act iPhone device as Beacon, No need to write single line of code. There is an application (Gemtot Sdk) itune link. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/gemtot-sdk/id967907684?mt=8                              Install that application in one iPhone device, now installed app act as transmitter and now run your actual code in another iPhone. Just the check the magic now.

Comment: iPhone device transmits signals only when the Installed application is in open state and must be in Beacon tab selected. I hope this could be useful those are search of this.

Answer (score 0):

u can create estimate beacons in any iOS device to make your device as transmitter..

Make use of beacon simulator app and create beacons manually.
Now run your app and monitor the beacon range..hardcode the same beacon I'd in code for testing..

Comment: Thank you, Can you please provide sample code how to create estimate beacons in any iOS device to make your device as transmitter. I followed  this link https://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/turning-iphone-ibeacon to create one iphone device for transmitter and another iphone device for receiver but not detected.